# C++ - Create function at runtime

Tags: c++, jit

In C++, I have to make some user-defined actions on each cells of a big table.
Because of the size of the table, I'd like not to use interpreted instructions but to compile during runtime a function that I will call on each cell.

The user-defined actions are pretty simple :

```
if ((state1 && state2) || state3) then change_a_value_in_memory
```

That's why I don't need to use the LLVM or other JIT libraries.

I hesitate to just use mmap and add the code in hex directly.

I'd like to know if it exists better solutions, or, if not, where I can find the basic format of a C++ function code to directly write it in memory.

Thanks, and sorry for my english :/

Comment: C++ is *usually* neither interpreted nor just-in-time compiled. If yours is, you might want to add what environment you are using.

Comment: Maybe you can hook up to some scripting language like Lua

Comment: If the conditions are really so simple, are you sure they are a bottleneck?  I would expect this kind of operation to be I/O bound.

Comment: All I need is just pure speed (the table can grow really big), that's why I prefer to use a function call instead of all the complexity of a lua compiler / handler.
The code will be as simple as a condition => a result. I'm creating an Cellular Automaton, the function will describe the rules of the automaton, and will be called on each cell of the grid.

Comment: Why not just write a parser for your "language"?

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most elegant, but it works always: generate a file with the C++ code of your function, call the compiler using `system()`, load the generated .so file using dlopen, and use the function!

This will take some time (due to the compiler call), but if you keep the function and maintain a database of the functions you already have, then you can save the amount of compilations.